# Embedding depending on URL

Tags: ee2

I am trying to do something that seems as if it should be simple but it's baffling me!

I have a template page that needs to embed something different depending on the URL.

There are three possible cases.

Case one is that segment_2 is blank. In this case I need to embed option A. Simple enough I think.

In Case two, segment_2 is not blank and contains the url_title of one of the products in this channel. I know the channel. I need to embed option B.

In case three, segment_2 is not blank and contains something else that is NOT the url_title of one of my products in this channel. Again I know the channel. I need to embed option A - the same as in the first case.

I have tried putting an if inside the exp:channel:entries tag pair, comparing {url_title and {segment_2) - that doesn't seem to work.

Rather than having anyone try to debug my code, how would anyone advise doing this? I am aware that I could be arranging my site in a different way, but I am where I am!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a no add-on way of doing this. I'm assuming you're not trying to get pagination going. That would change things.

```
{if segment_2 == ""}option A embed or direct code{/if}
{if segment_2 != ""}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="products" url_title="{segment_2}" require_entry="yes" ... }
     option B embed passing all variables necessary - or just put code here directly
     {if no_results}option C embed{/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen! I knew there had to be a simple way. I'll delete all the php variables I had there to try and get it going!